# Short story or poem about a one legged horse, African or Caribbean in origin

Tags: story-identification

I would have read this in UK secondary school sometime between 1995-2001. I believe it was part of a collection of work that was used in UK education, so it could be significantly older.

The story/poem was about a one legged horse. The horse was normal size for a horse but only had one large leg that it jumped around on.  It left large horseshoe prints where ever it went. I believe that the story/poem was of African or Caribbean origin with the horse creature being part of folklore.

The story/poem might have been part of a collection of non English authors. The language of the story/poem was slang/non-standard English.

The creature wasn't overtly evil, but I got the feeling it was a "bad" spirit, with its presence being an omen of ill intentions.

I'm not sure if this was a poem or short story but I believe it was only 1 or 2 sides of A4 paper at the most.

Comment: Not Afro-Carribean, nor a creature of ill omen, but it is a poem about a one legged horse. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_agtxbb17I  It does fit the date.

Comment: No that's not it, though I keep coming across this one whenever I search for it

Answer (score 4):

I've always remembered reading a F&SF short story about a one-legged horse by Geo. Alec Effinger, with his name credit printed exactly that way.

Turns out that that is pretty much the title:
["The Horse With One Leg" by George Alec Effinger.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71147)

It is a mostly feel-good story about the horse, his racing (!), and the young girl who pleaded for his life.

It is short, and well-suited to including in a children's book.
It does have the sad ending one might expect when any horse breaks his leg, though.

I would have bet money that I'd read it in Omni, but that apparently was not the case.

As you have discovered in your search, it is a hard-to-find niche subject.

It is not poetry, and this is a science fiction board, but it is the only reference to a one-legged horse I've found in decades.

It is not Afro-Caribbean, but George Alec Effinger lived in New Orleans.

It seems possible that he could have drawn inspiration for his story from an Afro-Caribbean poem, myth or legend.

If so, he could have written about that inspiration in one of his forewords, prefaces, or other blurbs.

I learned about Anansi the Spider in high school, so further investigation into folklore animals of Ghana and West Africa could show a similar legend of the horse.